# Tic-Tac-Toe AI using Minimax algorithm produces stack overflow error Java

Tags: java, recursion, artificial-intelligence, stack-overflow, minimax

Here is my code:

```
private int minvalue(char [] brd){

    int m = (int) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int v;
    ArrayList<Integer> action = actions(brd);

    for(int i = 0; i < action.size(); i++){
        int a = action.get(i);
        char [] nextbrd = result(brd, a, human);
        if(status(nextbrd)=='C') 
            v = maxvalue(nextbrd);
        else
            v = utility(nextbrd); 
        m = Math.min(v, m);
    }
    return m;     
}

private int maxvalue(char [] brd){
    int m = (int) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int v;
    ArrayList<Integer> action = actions(brd);

    for(int i = 0; i < action.size(); i++){
        int a = action.get(i);                
        char [] nextbrd = result(brd, a, agent);

            if(status(nextbrd)=='C')  //if the game is not yet over
                v = minvalue(nextbrd);
            else 
                v = utility(nextbrd);

            if(v==Math.max(m, v))  
                nextAction = a;
            m = Math.max(m, v);

    }return m;}
```

This produces stack overflow error. I checked my code many times but
I do not know what is wrong. Is it because the two functions call each other many times? Should I use threads ? Please help me

Comment: Then debug through it and see where it ends up calling itself to infinity. I would wager that it’s the if statement calling the other method and so on so forth.

Comment: @notyou the error says line v = minvalue(nextbrd) in maxvalue and v=maxvalue(nextbrd) in minvalue function

Comment: Yes, like I said, in the if statement.

Comment: @notyou yes. I know but I do not know how to fix it though

Comment: You need to figure out why *status(nextbrd)=='C'* all the time, as if so, it will eventually cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `i` in either function is ever anything other than 0?

Comment: @hatchet do you mean that i doesnt increment in both functions ?

Comment: Threads not necessary

Comment: @PatriciaSONE - It looks possible that you just bounce back and forth between minvalue and maxvalue, never getting past the first iteration of the loops. That will be the case if `status(result(brd, action.get(0), agent))` and `status(result(brd, action.get(0), human))` are both 'C'. You are never able to progress beyond i being 0.

Comment: @hatchet yes I figured that out after reading your first comment. I dont know how to fix that tho.

Comment: @PatriciaSONE - The problem may lie in your `actions` function, if it's not generating the correct values.